How to determine the first visible line relative to the window in SwiftUI using GeometryReader?
I am developing a Quran application using SwiftUI and have a ScrollView with a nested structure like this:
ScrollViewReader > ScrollView > LazyVStack > VStack > AttributedText(View) > TextViewWrapper(UIViewRepresentable) > TextView(UITextView)
I need to determine the first visible Ayah relative to the window as the user scrolls. Currently, I can determine the first Ayah of the first visible page, but I'm having trouble identifying the first visible Ayah within the page itself.
Here’s an example of how I am using GeometryReader:
  private func determineVisibleAyahOnPage(on page: Page, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> AyahDetails? {
    let visibleRect = geometry.frame(in: .global)
    let ayahs = page.ayahs
    
    if let firstVisibleAyah = ayahs.first {
      return AyahDetails(
        id: firstVisibleAyah.id,
        pageNumber: page.index
      )
    }
    
    return nil
  }


How can I accurately determine the first visible Ayah relative to the window, instead of just the first Ayah of the first visible page? What adjustments can I make to effectively get this information within my SwiftUI view?

Instead of using a ScrollViewReader, you could consider using .scrollTargetLayout combined with .scrollPosition. This automatically tracks the items as they are scrolled and might be much simpler.
